# What's the difference between AfxOleInit and OleInitialize?

Tags: c++, com, mfc, ole

When should I use one over the other? [MSDN doesn't provide any useful information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e91aseaz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using MFC you should use the `AfxOleInit` variant.  This calls both `OleInitialize` and creates / installs an MFC `IMessageFilter` object.  The second step is an MFC specific initialization step.

If you're not using MFC then just call `OleInitialize`

Comment: I always use `CoInitialize[Ex]()` instead of `OleInitialize()` in non-MFC apps. What am I missing? What could go wrong? Have I been living on the edge for so many years? :)

Comment: @JörgenSigvardsson See the remarks section at the end of `OleInitialize` doc page.  It lists all of the OLE specific actions which are initilaized by this call.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690134(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: AfxOleInit doesn't need to be uninitialized or I still have to call OleUninitialize at the end of execution?

Comment: @Fábio hmm, docs don't specify. I would be calling `OleUnitialize` though to be safe.

Comment: @JaredPar, just tested AfxOleInit/OleUnitialize and got an assertion failure, no need to OleUnitialize then. :)